# Efficient way of allocating memory for big unsigned integer

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, biginteger

I wrote a C++ class for big unsigned integer containing up to `10^5` decimal digits, it has got a `BASE = 10^9` and `std::vector<long long>` inside to store actual number -

for example `754564575693573452` is stored as

`std::vector<long long> number = {693573452, 754564575}`

In the constructor I resize this vector to always contain some fixed number of `long long` digits, lets say its 10^5, therefore a single addition of two big uints can have up to a 10^6 digits (which is `9 * 10^6` digits in `BASE = 10^1` numeral system), and similarly for multiplication...

So there's a 9 times speed up for all arithmetic operations but this is noticed only for a few calculations on big numbers, for a cases with a lot of computations the performance slows down, and this is because of the class design, my constructor and default constructor always call resize function as I said before, which is linear time routine.

```
void Big_uint::read_num_str(const std::string& num_str)
{
    // reading from num_str to number
}

Big_uint::Big_uint(const std::string& num_str = "0")
{
    number.resize( 1000000 );
    read_num_str(num_str);  
}

Big_uint::Big_uint(const long long& num)
{
    number.resize( 1000000 );
    char buff[ 20 ];
    _itoa_s(static_cast<int>(num), buff, 10);
    std::string s = buff;
    read_num_str(s);    
}
```

and all the arithmetic operations are implemented in this way

```
Big_uint operator + (const Big_uint& left, const Big_uint& right)
{
    Big_uint res; // resize() called here to initialize a vector
    // add algorithm
    return res; 
}

Big_uint operator * (const Big_uint& left, const Big_uint& right)
{
    Big_uint res; // resize() called here to initialize a vector

    // some multiplication algorithm here (currently only naive O(n^2) implemented)

    return res; 
}
```

Thus, they become inefficient.

How can I have the vector be already initialized depending on the input in operator overloads ?

I dont wan't to change operator overloads to a member functions like `add, mul, div` and pass them 3 parameters, where 3rd one would be a `res` - a preallocated zero initialized `Big_uint` to store the result of binary operation.

Comment: If you use a base of 10^9, why are you using `long long` to store a limb? A 32 bit integer would suffice. Also, using a decimal base makes divisions, multiplications, additions, etc. a little harder.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis 1) because of speed - `long long` has got maximum 18 digits while 32 bit only 9 digits, thus array of digits is twice less . 2) potential risk of 32 bit overflow -  Multiplying two 9 digit 32bit numbers won't fit in another 32 bit, while in 64bit it WILL fit

Comment: So use `long long` in the calculations, to catch any carry, but not to *store* the limbs. And the speed is much better with a full 32 bit integer. It is also better than with `long long`s. I have already written a BigInteger implementation (in Object Pascal though), and I have tried several scenarios. 32 bit integers turned out to be optimal, even in a 64 bit setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't preallocate storage this way. Don't preallocate at all. At every operation, you know (approximately) the size of the result. For add, it is the maximum of the inputs' size plus one. For mul, it is the sum of the inputs' size. Always try to allocate only the necessary space to hold the number.

So, the default constructor shouldn't allocate at all. Every other constructor should check the size of the input, and allocate the necessary space. Operators should (conservatively) approximate the necessary space, and allocate accordingly.

A side note: you should use base 2^32 instead of 10^9 (or 2^64 on a 64-bit machine): it has slightly less memory consumption, and performance will be much better.

Side note 2: sizeof(long long) is usually 8, so you waste memory if you only store numbers less than 10^9 in it.

Comment: yeah the size of result is known, but anyway it would be needed to allocate and initialize the result before using it

Comment: Using binary arithmetic is actually **much** better.  However it's somewhat more complex to interpret the result, i.e. convert this "huge" number into a series of decimal digits.

Comment: @ampawd: yes, but my suggestion is to allocate only the space necessary, so it won't slow down the calculation. It has a huge difference between allocating only the necessary space and always allocating 8MB as your example does (supposing that sizeof(long long)==8). It is not just slow, but eats memory fast.

Comment: thats not waste of memory, it is done to avoid overflow, for example when multiplying two 32bit integers

Comment: @ampawd: it is. In this case, you have to split the resulting 64-bit integer into two 32-bit parts, and store these 2 integers at neighboring indices.

Comment: @geza where's the difference then ?? to store 64 bit as a one limb or as 2 two separated limbs ? same amount of memory is used -  I'm not understanding what you mean

Comment: @ampawd: this is the correct way to handle overflow. If you store a 64-bit number into the limb after a multiply, then how would you use this number afterwards? How would you multiply this number? If you use base 10^9, then you should never store a larger number into a limb. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @ampawd: it is the same concept how one handles overflow at add. Suppose you add 99 and 99 together (in base 100): in this case, lowest limb becomes 98, next limb becomes 1. Not the solution where only one limb with the value of 198. If you do 99*99 (=9801), lowest limb is 1, next limb is 98.

Comment: @ampawd: if you don't understand this concept, I recommend you to first implement the usual grade school algorithms (base 10)

Comment: @ampawd: no, it is not the same. How would be the space the same? Using long long (64-bit) as a limb, where base is 10^9 (so limb values >=10^9 is forbidden), uses twice as much memory.

Comment: For every 32bit limb there should be another limb beside to handle overflow the way you described before, thus same memory used ( 9999 + 9999 overflows in base = 10^2, so you store additional two limbs to store 1 in each, thus twice memory used as with long long for a limbs, however 32 bit seems correct to me because it shoudln be greater than base, also using pow of 2 for base i find inconvinient due to the required conversion to decimal, which can be an expensive operation

Comment: I'd don't quite follow your method. I don't think it actually works... in my method, there is only one "extra" limb for the whole number (which is absolutely needed to store the number). In your method, there is an "extra" limb for each limb (and I don't understand how it is handled after it becomes non-zero). As for the pow2 base: yes, conversion to decimal becomes expensive. But every other operation is much cheaper. Usually, decimal conversion is a rare operation (it is only needed in input/output). But if your usage is different, feel free to use a decimal representation.

Comment: @ampawd: '"For every 32bit limb there should be another limb beside to handle overflow". this "another" limb is the next limb, which will be used anyway at the next cycle (so it not an extra limb just for storing overflow)